# Riemann series theorem for integrals

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

I was wondering whether there is an integral analogue of the Riemann series theorem. That is if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function such that $\int_\infty^\infty f(x)dx$ doesn't exist, is there then, for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$ two functions $g(t), h(t)$ such that $lim_{t\to\infty}g(t)=\infty=lim_{t\to\infty}h(t)$ and such that
$$lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{-h(t)}^{g(t)}f(x)dx=a$$
After a bit of pondering this is false in general, like if $f(x)=1$, but I am wondering what hypothesis I can strengthen and what conclusion I can weak, for it to become true. My best guess so far is that there should exist at least one such pair $(g,h)$ so that the limit is equal to something. But I can't seem to conclude anything more.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: This won’t work. Note that Riemann’s theorem is called the “rearrangement” theorem for a reason: one can find a permutation of the sequence whose sum is the given value. So, here, you should try to look for a function, call it $\alpha$ such that the composition $f\circ \alpha$ has integral as you’d like. The point is to exploit the positivity and negativity of the function in order to produce the final desired value. I haven’t fully thought things through, but this is the first thought I have.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, thanks